# Why isn't my Stack Overflow reputation global on Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, stack-exchange

I wonder why the reputation I have on Stack Overflow isn't shared across the whole Stack Exchange network and hence does not unlock advanced editing privileges and commenting?

Well, I believe if I help someone with, let's say, CSS, which I understand, then I should be able to get help in other communities with all the benefits (i.e. add more that 3 links to post or comment on existing questions/answers).

It might be a good idea to change that.

Note: this question about unlocking perks, not about being recognized as an expert in a different community.

Comment: Because experts on programming aren't necessarily experts in, say, wood working :-)

Comment: hmmm yes.... if there are ONLY sites about coding and they just vary in the environment.... however, when there are gaming, RPG, boardgame, religions, history, movies, etc. I don't want the guy who know Buffy the Vampire Slayer by heart to have more rep than me on a coding site.... On scifi & Fantasy, however...

Comment: @yellowantphil yeah, but not for long, if it is up to me.

Comment: Wow guys you are really mean.
@Patrice well I think if i help someone with what i know i should get the bonuses (posting multiple link etc.) in other communities. You think about it as a way to show that you are expert, however I was talking about having the bonuses.

Comment: @yellowantphil the fairness might seem a bit weird but what I meant by it is that If I help in something I am good at I should be awarded with the bonuses across communities.

Comment: @TomasB that already exists,  but you need more than 43 rep to get it. Glorfindel's answer covers it pretty well.

Comment: Who was mean to you?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yep I just wanted to correct the misconception about my question. People thought that I am talking about the expertise which wasn't the point and therefore this post got so bad reputation.

Comment: @Will the way people replied. It doesn't necessarily mean that they insulted me in any way. But they replied like I was totally dumb. I just wanted to help with what i experienced so far. I needed a help in Arduino community but was not able to write the questin the way I wanted because my reputation wasn't shared across the stack exchange and therefore I couldn't for example paste multiple links. Then I felt like it's useless to help with CSS when I need a help somewhere else and my point are not shared. That's all

Comment: @TomasB people read the question and reacted to content of it. This is part of SE which you are expected to learn while gaining initial reputation. If you want to "correct ... question" - you [edit] it, not add comments (and this is another thing you learn...)

Comment: Note: need for multiple links is potential sign of bad non-self-contained question... You may want to review post you've planned and make sure all information that is needed actually present inline in the post.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You are right - most of the time it means a bad question. However sometimes it is way more efficient and reader friendly to post images which gives much more information in a much shorter time + none of us want to read a very long question which could be shorten with few links. But thats for another discussion and right here it's OT I believe. However thanks for you input, I appreciate it.

Comment: @TomasB well if you mean "keep my perks unlocked", then say so man! In any case, there are other reasons not to do that. Some perks are HEAVILY made for moderation. Each site moderates itself differently. My Close-votes on a site where I don't know the quality standards shouldn't count because I have points in ANOTHER site.

Comment: @Patrice I see. Yeah I understand your point and you are right. I would say that there should be selected perks (Since I am not a native speaker I didn't know how you call it like that - that's the answer for the question "well if you mean "keep my perks unlocked", then say so man!") which actually needs an expertise to gain them, BUT since I already got an answer that after 200 rep my basic perks will unlock everywhere, there is no need for that. Thanks

Comment: @TomasB no problem :) and.... Don't worry about the perceived rudeness... (If any of that was mine btw i do want to apologize as no slight was intended :) ) That is just the weird beast that is meta. And yeah i get where you are coming from... Some basic features should be platform wide and not limited to where it was earned. Depending on the exact selection, i would likely approve of such a change.

Comment: Voted to re-open (resonable request after edit), but I believe votes are correct as feature-request is asking to implement  existing feature.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [How does "Reputation" work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work):

> #### What does Reputation do?
>
> As a registered user, your reputation on the site is a part of your identity on the site. It reflects, to an extent, your familiarity with the site, the amount of subject matter expertise you have and the level of respect your peers have for you. It can generally only be gained when other users of the site approve of the content you provide.

---

Simply put, subject matter expertise on site A does not equal subject matter expertise on site B.

The 'familiarity with the site' part actually *is* global – it's called the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus). Once you reach 200 reputation on any Stack Exchange site, you'll receive a bonus of 100 reputation on all other sites. This does *not* prove you have any knowledge about the site's scope, but it *does* prove that you know the basic rules of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 7):

> I believe if I help someone with let's say CSS which I understand, then I should be able to **get help** in other communities with all the benefits.

You can. Reputation does not affect your ability ask questions in other communities. Anybody can ask questions, regardless of reputation, on any site in the network.

Comment: What I meant by that is that I can't post lest say more than 3 links even though I have gained reputation somewhere else. Which is just not very fair in my opinion.

Comment: @TomasB if you had simply stated that (and dropped all this "fair" BS) you'd have a better discussion/feature request.

Comment: Well yeah. English is not my first language so in for me it sounded obvious what I meant. Seems that I was wrong, maybe next time I'll be more specific. Thanks anyway

Comment: @TomasB well, the association bonus will take of those limitations.