# Will my reputation be the same for all Stack Overflow communities?

Tags: support, reputation

Boy did I get a scare! I was in Stack Overflow when I clicked Stack Overflow Meta without noticing. All my history, except my reputation disappeared.

Is it that our reputation always remain the same for different communities?

Comment: Only between main and meta sites, for reputation that is. You just earned you first meta badge for doing your autobiography, Congrats!

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250077/will-reputation-on-mso-be-reflected-on-so and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338011/why-isnt-my-stack-overflow-reputation-global-on-stack-exchange